# Azure DNS with GoDaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, godaddy

I have purchased my domain from GoDaddy. I have hosted my website in  Azure VMSS with Azure Application Gateway. In Azure DNS, I have create the zone for mine website. In GoDaddy, I have added Name Servers that I got from Azure DNS. But my site is not accessible. 
Also when I am trying to do nslookup "site.com" it is giving me error as "** server can't find site.com: NXDOMAIN"
Please help

Comment: Gee, a good start would be to tell us the actual domain name so that we could actually give you accurate answers. As it stands now your problem COULD LITERALLY BE ANYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

You have not changed your NS records for the domain to point to Azure DNS. When you created your DNS zone in Azure it would have given you 4 NS records to use, you need to change your domain to use these. At the moment it is returning these:

```
ns55.domaincontrol.com. | 216.69.185.28
ns56.domaincontrol.com. | 208.109.255.28
ns55.domaincontrol.com. | 2607:f208:206::1c
ns56.domaincontrol.com. | 2607:f208:302::1c
```